# Calculate CRC32b in Java

Tags: java, crc32

I use java.util.zip.CRC32 which I understand implements CRC32 (and not CRC32b), but it seems like I need to use CRC32b instead of CRC32.

is there a Java open source code I can use for CRC32b calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRC32b is a coined term if I remember correctly, equal to CRC32 with the 4 bytes reversed.

```
int crc32b(int crc) {
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    buf.putInt(crc); // BIG_ENDIAN by default.
    buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    return buf.getInt(0);
}
```

For instance for input '1':

```
byte b = (byte) '1';
CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
crc.update(b);

System.out.printf("%x%n", crc.getValue());
int finalCRC = crc32b((int)crc.getValue());
System.out.printf("%x%n", finalCRC);
```

Output:

```
83dcefb7
b7efdc83
```

Given your example the conclusion: java CRC32 (*without* reversal) is fine.

Comment: I compared your code output when the input is just 1 (the number), it outputs 16777216 while online crc32b calculator output 83dcefb7 so I guess it's not the same. Thanks.

Comment: Did a search, and found [this](http://www.pal-blog.de/entwicklung/perl/crc32-vs-crc32b.html) but I am sure your CRC32b is more.

Comment: Extended the answer, with the devastating conclusion, that CRC32 seems to be just fine.

Comment: I'm not sure I get you. In your code you pass crc (which is of type CRC32) to method crc32b that expect int.

Comment: Plus, I can't compile System.out.println("%x%n", crc.getValue()); am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I tested the code in a bit other form. Corrected.